# Android. ACRA. Is putCustomData thread safe

Tags: android, acra

I can't seem to find the answer to this question I'm having:

Is the method from the ACRA library ...

`ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData(Name, Content);`

... thread safe?

I'd like to call it from two different threads and I'm not sure if i should or not.

I've searched through the documentation but I wasn't able to find anything related to this unfortunately, or maybe I'm just a bad Googleler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I've figure it out.

Looking through the code I've noticed that the `putCustomData` method is in fact a call to a `HashMap's` method, more precisely `put`.

Upon further search I've found that the method `put` is not synchronized.

So the answer is no, calling `putCustomData` from two different threads can create problems for you.

**For a solution to the problem**: see *323go*'s idea below. In my case, I already had a singleton class which I used, so I just placed a synchronized method in that class in which I called the `putCustomData` method.

***Note:*** If I am wrong, someone please let me know, but this is what I was able to find out.

Comment: HashMap is indeed not thread-safe. However, you could make it so by changing the assignment to a `ConcurrentHashMap`, or using `Collections.synchronizedMap( ... )`. Of course, that would require modification of your ACRA source, and a synchronized block (or method) within your singleton are less intrusive alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure, buy some insurance:

```
ErrorReporter er = ACRA.getErrorReporter();
synchronized( er ) {
    er.putCustomData( ..., .... );
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea ... If i won't be able to find the answer i'll definitely go this route. Thanks. (Btw ... that was funny :) )

Comment: Since ACRA is OSS, you could just peek in their code. And please post back what you learn, that'll save some time for future askers.